# Properly dismissing either popover ViewController or modal ViewController

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ipad, uiviewcontroller

I am building a universal App which is supposed to present a view controller to add stuff. On iPad, this is presented in a `popover` and on iPhone in a modal `viewController`. I am using the presenting `ViewController` as a `delegate`.

Now, if I want to assign the `properController`, I have to:

```
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"popoverAddSegue"])  
    self.myPopOver = [(UIStoryboardPopoverSegue * )segue popoverController];
if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"modalAddSegue"])
    self.myModalView = [segue destinationViewController];
```

thus using two properties and only ever assigning one.
Then, in my delegate function, I again have to differentiate:

```
if(self.myPopOver)
    [self.myPopOver dismissPopoverAnimated:YES];
if(self.myModalView)
    [self.myModalView dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

The problem obviously is that `UIPopoverController` does not inherit from `UIViewController`... Is there any elegant way of doing this? Factory or something? I hate having customised code in a `viewController` that should be agnostic about how it presents its `viewControllers`...

Answer (score 0):

I use this

```
 if (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone) {
     // The device is an iPhone or iPod touch.
 } else {
     // The device is an iPad => show library true popover.
 }
```

This is not exactly what you ask for, but it have a good point : you can have the same segue identifier for both iPhone and iPad.

Now to have 1 similar method for both (popover / modalVC), may be you can add to both a new category with a method name dismissAnimated: